# Error: Unable to load OraOps10.dll

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, oracle, dll

I have NT services compiled with 32 bit version of oracle client on windows 7, but when I run this service on windows 2008 I get error: Unable to load OraOps10.dll.

I guess that this is because I have newer version of oracle client on the server then on my development station, but I can not install old (32 bit version) client on server, and can not install 64 bit client on development station...

So may be there is some solution like manually to copy some files and change values in registry?

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I copied all source to server, installed there Visual Studio and compiled project in x64 bit mode with x64 bit version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll. Despite the fact that this is not so good way, it eventually work now. Now all I need is to get access to repository from server for get source code every time I will compile it.