# OraOps10.dll loading problem

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, oracle, 64-bit

I have ASP.NET web service built on windows 7 in 32 bit. All dependences of this service compiled in Release mode in x64 bit. Now, I'm installed it on windows 8 64 bit and when I'm access to this service I get error "Could not load OraOps10.dll". I doesn't succeed to find any thing about this problem with oracle client in context of x32-x64 bit incompatibility in internet.

Have you any idea?
Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/129870/error-unable-to-load-oraops10-dll

Comment: No, this is not duplicate, because there is IIS environment and here is direct .NET Framework, it has different symptoms and solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, like it was in my other question:
[Error: Unable to load OraOps10.dll](https://serverfault.com/questions/129870/error-unable-to-load-oraops10-dll),
I copied all source to server, installed there Visual Studio and compiled project in x64 bit mode with x64 bit version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll. Despite the fact that this is not so good way, it eventually work now. Now all I need is to get access to repository from server for get source code every time I will compile it.

Answer (score 0):

http://i-m-code.com/blog/post/2009/03/05/Solving-e28098OraOps10dlle28099-Error.aspx

Comment: What means: "The reference change should ONLY occur on the build server ( 64 bit ) NOT on the local developer machines ( 32 bit )."?

Comment: Sorry, but we don't build our solution with TeamCity, and if we will do so, that not will be soon... So have you other, Visual Studio's solution to the problem?

Comment: But I will try to build this with 64 bit Oracle.DataAccess